# Enum for ButtonStyle in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

It is possible to set the button style this way...?

```
Button() { }
   .buttonStyle(.default)
```

Instead of this...?

```
Button() { }
   .buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
```

I tried to code an extension but it doesn't work.

```
extension ButtonStyle {
    static var `default`: DefaultButtonStyle {
        DefaultButtonStyle()
    }
}
```

It says: `Static member 'default' cannot be used on protocol metatype 'ButtonStyle.Protocol'`

Comment: Compiler have already answered you. The `ButtonStyle` is generic protocol (it has associated type) - you can't do that. May I ask - what are you trying to do here? - It is already default by default when no `.buttonStyle` provided.

Comment: `Default` was an example. Would be nice to have a .link, .rounded, .bordered, .borderless styles without searching in the autocompletion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a demo of possible approach - use own modifier and own enum, so have complete control on everything.

Usage

```
Button("Demo") {}
    .myStyle(.default)
```

And helper extensions

```
enum MyButtonStyle {
    case `default`
    case borderless
    // .. extend with any custom here
}

extension Button {

    @ViewBuilder
    func myStyle(_ style: MyButtonStyle) -> some View {
        switch style {
            case .default:
                self.buttonStyle(DefaultButtonStyle())
            case .borderless:
                self.buttonStyle(BorderlessButtonStyle())
           // .. extend with any custom here
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Another solution:

```
extension ButtonStyle where Self == BorderlessButtonStyle {
    
    internal static var borderless: BorderlessButtonStyle {
        BorderlessButtonStyle()
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Button("Demo") {}
    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
```