# SwiftUI conditional .buttonStyle

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to change the style of a button based on a condition like this:

```
.buttonStyle((selection == index) ? .borderedProminent : .bordered)
```

Strangely it throws this error:

```
Type 'ButtonStyle' has no member 'borderedProminent'
```

I suppose I am making a syntax mistake?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/64769260/12299030?

Comment: I don' think so - if I change the code to:

.buttonStyle((selection == index) ? BorderedButtonStyle() : BorderlessButtonStyle())

it throws this error:

Result values in '? :' expression have mismatching types 'BorderedButtonStyle' and 'BorderlessButtonStyle'

Comment: You did not read that answer carefully - it does not use ternary operator `cause it is not allowed in this situation.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I will use the workaround then.